# Change application theme at runtime after making an api call from an onClick event

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am new to next.js and react and having trouble figuring this issue out.
My application requires me to change the entire theme of the page at runtime after making an api call.
I am using next.js react and material UI.

What I tried to do is to create a react context and use context it in one of the nested children, but unfortunately I cannot use it inside an onClick function which defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do.

Ideal flow

1. in _app.ts declare a theme object as a parameter to ThemeProvider
2. in one of the pages' buttons have an onClick event which will make an async call to an api and retrieve a color value
3. create a theme object based on that value
4. Swap the app theme to the new theme.

What I got so far is this but it seems very clunky.

```js
export default function MyApp(props: any) {
    const { Component, pageProps } = props;
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(muiTheme);
    const value = { theme, setTheme };

    React.useEffect(() => {

        // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
        const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
        if (jssStyles && (jssStyles.parentElement !== null)) {
            jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Head>
                <title>My page</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
            </Head>

            <ThemeProvider theme={value.theme}>

// IS THERE A WAY NOT TO USE MY OWN ThemeContext.Provider and use MUI Theme provider instead to change a theme?

                <ThemeContext.Provider value={value}>
                    {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
                    <CssBaseline />
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </ThemeContext.Provider>
            </ThemeProvider>

        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Now inside one of the nextjs pages I have a button which makes an api call inside of the updateRoom method. However inside of that function I am unable to use useContext hook.

Is there a better way to approach this?

```js
<Button
            onClick={() => updateRoom(room, flowActionId)}
            ...
```

What I would like to do inside of the updateRoom method is this

```js
async function updateRoom(room: any, flowActionId: any) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.put(`/api/room/${room.id}`,
            {
                flow_action_id: Number(flowActionId)
            });



    const leTheme = createTheme({
        palette: {
          primary: {
            main: '#123123', <--- parse my api call and set this color
          }
        },
      });

      const { theme, setTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
      setTheme(leTheme); <--- set the app theme here.



    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having look at my code. I tried doing the same thing

i have created a seperate ThemeContext file like so..

```
const ThemeContext = createContext();

const ThemeProvide = (props) => {
  const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState({
    primary: "#003e7e",
    secondary: "#ADEFD1FF",
    type: prefersDarkMode ? "dark" : "light",
    background: "#fafafa",
    paper: "#ffffff",
  });

  const themePalette = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: theme.primary,
      },
      secondary: {
        main: theme.secondary,
      },
      background: {
        default: theme.background,
        paper: theme.paper,
      },
      type: theme.type,
    },
  });
   
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={[theme, setTheme]}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={themePalette}>
        <CssBaseline />
       {props.children}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { ThemeContext, ThemeProvide };
```

Now i wrap the whole _app.js with this ThemeProvide Component //Notice the difference b/w ThemeProvider and ThemeProvide Component
Im sure you can name it better than me

```
import { ThemeProvide } from "../state/theme";

 const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
      useEffect(() => {
        const jssStyles = document.querySelector("#jss-server-side");
        if (jssStyles) {
          jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
        }
      }, []);
      return (
        <>
            <ThemeProvide>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ThemeProvide>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default MyApp;
```

Now i can use the ThemeContext in any of my pages or components

like so

```
const [theme,setTheme ] = useContext(ThemeContext)
//Use setTheme to change your Theme
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my issue as i cannot call useContext method from an onClick function.

Comment: you dont have to call useContext in onClick, use useContext in ur component as a hook, than use `setTheme`  in onClick function or u can pass `setTheme` to your updateRoom function as a argument like so `onClick={() => updateRoom(room, flowActionId, setTheme)}`